# Creating a Virtual Host for Apache MAMP

Tags: php, apache, mamp, virtualhost

I'm trying to create a virtual host on my MAMP setup so I can access http://api.localhost for a PHP API I'm trying to build with Slim. Here's the code I've appended to my `httpd.conf` file:

```
Name VirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/slim"
    ServerName api.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

When I restart the server and try to start it up again with this new configuration, it simply won't load. I commented out the new code and it loads fine. Any ideas?

Comment: The `NameVirtualHost` directive is one word, no spaces. Could be part of the problem.

Comment: Check out your Apache error log, hopefully it contains some hints you can post to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this line

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

instead of yours

and I think you can remove the first line too...